# Error Occured after installation of Intel HAXM

Tags: android, flutter, dart

What should we do if we still get errors after installing INTEL HAXM Through sdk Manager In Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow steps
windows :

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off.
2. From the window disable Hyper-V options.

3 Reboot your machine.

NOTE : If virtualization is disabled in the BIOS, you need to enable it.